# Scala type inference and implicit conversions

Tags: scala, type-inference, implicit-conversion

The following code works:

```scala
scala> import scala.language.implicitConversions
import scala.language.implicitConversions

scala> implicit val longToInt = (l: Long) => l.toInt
longToInt: Long => Int = $$Lambda$1821/0x000000010086e840@52bd9a27

scala> def printInt(n: Int) = println(n)
printInt: (n: Int)Unit

scala> val opt: Option[Long] = None
opt: Option[Long] = None

scala> val n = opt.getOrElse(0L)
n: Long = 0

scala> printInt(n)
0
```

However, the compiler throws a type mismatch error if we nest the `getOrElse` expression inside of the function call:

```scala
scala> printInt(opt.getOrElse(0L))
<console>:16: error: type mismatch;
 found   : AnyVal
 required: Int
       printInt(opt.getOrElse(0L))
                             ^
```

Why does `opt.getOrElse(0L)` have type AnyVal?

Scala 2.12.8

Comment: I ran the same code using 2.12.8 version. There was no such error

Comment: I'm getting the issue here as well as on my own pc: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/e6goaBkJTCWxErIZbSqjCg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
printInt(opt.getOrElse(0L))
```

`opt.getOrElse(0L)` is typed with expected type `Int`. [`Option#getOrElse`'s signature is](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Option.html#getOrElse[B%3E:A](default:=%3EB):B)

```
getOrElse[B >: A](default: ⇒ B): B
```

Because it's generic, the compiler tries to find `B` such that `opt.getOrElse[B](0L)` has type `Int`. So `B` has to satisfy constraints `B >: Long` (because `A` in the above signature is `Long`) and `B <: Int` (from the return type). Obviously there's no such `B`. Scala specification says this must be an error, but doesn't say which, and here the compiler happens to report it after guessing `B = AnyVal`.

Another way to fix it is to specify the expected type for `opt.getOrElse(0L)`:

```
printInt(opt.getOrElse(0L): Long)
```

Or the type parameter:

```
printInt(opt.getOrElse[Long](0L))
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature of **getOrElse** is:

```
def getOrElse[B1 >: B](key: A, default: ⇒ B1): B1
```

**printInt(opt.getOrElse(0L))** tells Scala that B1 ought to be Long, but Long is not a super-type of Int. The common supertype instead is AnyVal. Therefore you cannot make that assignment.

Try casting the result to a Long instead:

```
printInt(opt.getOrElse(0L).toLong)
```

Comment: This is the wrong `getOrElse`. In addition, the problem is exactly Scala _not_ understanding that the type parameter needs to be `Long`: specifying it will fix the problem!